# Choosing the correct join in SQL Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, join

Given the following tables :

```
CREATE TABLE TrainInfo
  (
    Trainnumber       INTEGER NOT NULL ,
    nbSits1st         INTEGER NOT NULL ,
    nbAvail1st        INTEGER NOT NULL ,
    nbSits2e          INTEGER NOT NULL ,
    nbAvail2e         INTEGER NOT NULL ,
    Journey_journeyID INTEGER NOT NULL
  ) ;
ALTER TABLE TrainInfo ADD CONSTRAINT TrainInfo_PK PRIMARY KEY ( Trainnumber) ;


CREATE TABLE Journey
  (
    journeyID     INTEGER NOT NULL ,
    departure     VARCHAR2 (45) NOT NULL ,
    arrival       VARCHAR2 (45) NOT NULL ,
    departuretime DATE NOT NULL ,
    arrivaltime   DATE NOT NULL ,
    distance      INTEGER NOT NULL ,
    period        VARCHAR2 (45)
  ) ;
  ALTER TABLE Journey ADD CONSTRAINT Journey_PK PRIMARY KEY ( journeyID) ;


ALTER TABLE TrainInfo ADD CONSTRAINT TrainInfo_FK FOREIGN KEY ( Journey_journeyID)
REFERENCES Journey ( journeyID) ON DELETE CASCADE ;
```

I would like to find the "trainnumber, departure, arrival, departuretime, arrivaltime" in this. I tried :

```
CREATE VIEW TrainsPossibles AS 
      SELECT trainnumber, departure, arrival, departuretime, arrivaltime 
        FROM TrainInfo 
      NATURAL JOIN Journey 
       ORDER BY departure;
```

My problem is, it select 112 (14*8) rows, while i have only 14 trainsInfo and 8 journeys in my DB at the moment.

First of all, why does it creates so many rows ? I thought it would join when the foreign key match the primary key, so 14 times at best.

Second : what is the correct query or join here ? (full join on FK = PK ?)

Try with a condition :

```
 SELECT trainnumber, departure, arrival, departuretime, arrivaltime
 FROM TrainInfo JOIN
      Journey
      ON TrainInfo.journey_journeyid = Journey.journeyid AND nbAvail1st != 0 AND nbAvail2e != 0;
 ORDER BY departure;
```

Comment: http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/ oh, and this context, you'd be better off saying "choose the CORRECT join". `right join` is just too confusing - there's only one `right join`.

Comment: Both solution (join and left join) you guys proposed works wonderfully. But what's the concrete difference between the two of them ?

Comment: read the page I linked to. it shows (visually) the difference between the various joins

Comment: @Marc B. Ah great, thanks. Last question : I edited the original post with a query. Is that correct (the same but with 2 more conditions) ?

Comment: technically, `join` should only include conditions related to the decision on whether to join or not. the `nb... !=` stuff should go into a `where` clause instead. but this is more of a stylistic decision than anything, and sometimes you have to do `join` conditions like this that wouldn't work in `where`.

Answer (score 1):

A *Natural Join* returns combinations of records with corresponding fields of one table against another table. That's why you get so many records.

To get what you are needing, you should perform a "left join"  rather than a "natural join", with an "on" condition of "on TrainInfo.Journey_journeyID = 
Journey.JourneyID". A *left join* returns all the records on the "left side" of the query and all the records on the "right side" that match your "join condition" If no records from the "right table" (Journey) exist, you'll get "nulls" in those columns. To get only results where records exist in both tables, use LEFT INNER JOIN.

```
SELECT trainnumber, departure, arrival, departuretime, arrivaltime 
  FROM TrainInfo 
  LEFT JOIN Journey 
  on TrainInfo.Journey_journeyID = JourneyID
ORDER BY departure
```

Comment: Both solution (join and left join) you guys proposed works wonderfully. But what's the concrete difference between the two of them ?

Comment: Left join returns ALL records from the "left side" table, and nulls for unmatched records on the right-hand table. Join alone returns only those records for which there is a match across the join condition. Plain "join" is also *generally* synonymous with "inner join".

Answer (score 1):

First, don't use `NATURAL JOIN`.  It depends on the columns defined in the table for the join keys. Unfortunately, it goes strictly by name and *not* by declared foreign key references.  If there are no matching keys, then you get a cartesian product.

Your query is:

```
 SELECT trainnumber, departure, arrival, departuretime, arrivaltime
 FROM TrainInfo NATURAL JOIN
      Journey
 ORDER BY departure;
```

None of the columns have the same name, so the `JOIN` ends up being a Cartesian product.  I think you want:

```
 SELECT trainnumber, departure, arrival, departuretime, arrivaltime
 FROM TrainInfo JOIN
      Journey
      ON TrainInfo.journey_journeyid = Journey.journeyid
 ORDER BY departure;
```